# Are the reals a "subset" of the class of ordinals

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers, ordinals

I am not sure if it's even correct to use subset in this context but I'm sure it gets the point across. I just want to know if the class of ordinals includes non-integer elements like $4.5$, $\pi$, $e$ among others. And if yes, can we combine the transfinite ordinals with non-integer constants like $\omega + \frac{1}{4}$ or $2\pi\cdot\omega$ for example?

Comment: If you assume the continuum hypothesis, $\mathbb{R}=\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: No, the reals are not a subset of the ordinal numbers.

Comment: Asking whether the reals are a subset of the class of ordinals is equivalent to asking "is every real number an ordinal?" The answer is: it depends on how you are precisely defining the real numbers, and how are you defining the ordinals.

Comment: @VincentBatens the continuum hypothesis says the second equality but not the first.

Comment: @Joe it does depend but it requires axioms beyond ZFC to define the reals as a subset of the ordinals (if we wanted to do that for some reason). Such a thing would constitute a definable well-ordering of the reals. (Plus, seems the question is more a structural one than about bare sets.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen $\mathbb{R}=2^{\aleph_0}$ by definition. I put them in the wrong order

Comment: @VincentBatens $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R$. (Unless by $2^{\aleph_0}$ you mean the set of all functions $\aleph_0\to 2$, in which case it is (definably interchangable with) $\mathbb R$, but is not equal to $\aleph_1$, regardless of CH).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ye I might have to put cardinalities around them. But okay, they are equal up to some bijection. I left a comment on the answer, where I explain what I meant. It all depends on what you mean with "having $\mathbb{R}$ in the ordinals", or I am just way to tired to think at the moment :)

Comment: @VincentBatens If that's the criterion (mere existence of an injection into an ordinal), then under AC "being a subset of an ordinal" loses any distinction. I think there are structural issues here that supersede this (the OP seems to be asking if e.g. 'the ordinal 3/2' makes sense, which it doesn't), but even if we're just talking about being a set theoretical subset, there is a problem here, which I mention in response to Joe above, that it is not possible (with only ZFC) to define the reals as a subset of the ordinals. Sure, AC says there is a bijection, but we can't necessarily define one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinal numbers arise when one tries to construct natural numbers within the axioms of the set theory. Basically, you start from 0 as an empty set, and then you define operation of "adding 1" in a language of simple operations on sets. As a consequence, you note that, using this definition, nothing stops you from "adding 1" to the whole set of naturals, and there you go.

But reals cannot be obtained from repeated "addition of 1" to naturals, so no, they aren't included in ordinals. Instead, one first constructs rationals from naturals and then uses Dedekind cuts (or any alternative approach).

**However**, within the funny number system called surreal numbers, one can define *both ordinals and reals* and give a meaning to expressions like $2\pi \cdot \omega$, $\frac{\omega}{2}$ and so on. I highly recommend "Surreal Numbers" by Knuth if you're interested in this topic.

As John Conway wrote about them:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, ordinals are not just about adding one. It is an generalization of well ordered sets and by the axiom of choice, every set has a well order. Since every cardinal is also an ordinal, one sees that $\text{card}(\mathbb{R})$ is an ordinal and so one can map $\mathbb{R}$ bijectively into the ordinals or am I completely missing something. (Note that the isomorphism will of course not be order preserving, since $\mathbb{R}$ is not well ordered for the natural order)

Comment: @VincentBatens As already said in the comments to the OP, it depends on your definition of reals. In my answer, I took a constructive approach (in my opinion the most natural one and in agreement with the original question). Note that, under your definitions, everything becomes an ordinal (since any set can be well-ordered by AC), so this notion kind of loses it's meaning. Although, I acknowledge that I don't have enough experience in this field and may be wrong.

Comment: you are looking for an order-preserving embedding into the ordinals, while I am looking for an embedding. It indeed depends on the meaning of "reals in ordinals".